# Why does vibrational motion not have a significant impact on heat capacity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

The bonds of a molecule are rigid - they can stretch and bend, which leads to additional degrees of freedom. However, according to (Young, Freedman, & Ford, 2011),

> Resulting vibrations lead
>   to additional degrees of freedom and additional energies. For most diatomic gases,
>   however, vibrational motion does not contribute appreciably to heat capacity. The
>   reason for this is a little subtle and involves some concepts of quantum mechanics.

Source: Young, H., Freedman, R., & Ford, L. (2011). University physics with modern physics (1st ed.). Boston, Mass.: Addison-Wesley.

Comment: How much physics do you have beyond that chapter of the text? There is a reason the authors decided to skip on explaining it at that point in the book.

Comment: You could also consider rotational motion of diatomic molecules: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatomic_molecule

Comment: @dmckee There is a significant portion on QM after this chapter.

Comment: The reason for neglecting vibrations at human-compatible temperatures is bound up in the quantization of the vibrational modes (the thermal energy per mode is much less than the energy of first excitation for the vibrational degree of freedom). But the author may want to put off talking about that until quantization has been brought up in the first place.

Comment: Vibrations are significant  in diatomic gases a temperatures upwards of 600K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation that says something like

> because thermal energy is to low to excite transitions between vibrational states then it can not be stored in vibrational degrees of freedom and so it does not contribute to heat capacity

does not really explain anything and I think it is kind of wrong.

If the energy gap between the first two vibrational states($n=0$ and $n=1$) of a molecule is $w$ then we only need the total energy of the system to be greater than $w$ for the mode $n=1$ to have a non zero probability. This is because each non forbidden state for the whole system should be occupied equiprobably.

So even for low temperature the vibrational modes do store thermal energy. But they contribute very little to the heat capacity.

**Proof:**

The heat capacity per degree of freedom can derived using Maxwell–Boltzmann statistics: the probabilty $ p(n) $ for a small subsystem (or a molecule) to have the energy $E(n)$ is proportional to,

$$\begin{align}
p(n) &\propto g(n)\ e^{-E(n)/k_B T}
\end{align}$$

where $ k_B $ is Boltzmann’s constant and $ g(n) $ is the degeneracy ,i.e., the number of state for this subsystem with energy $E(n)$. It can be zero.

We can apply this formula to translational, rotational or vibrational modes for one or several molecules. Let's use it for a vibrational mode (=one degree of freedom) and we can take this mode to be an harmonic oscillator with energy  $ E(n) = nw $. Then the probability to be in state $ n $ is $ p(n)=N Exp(-nw/k_B T) $ With $ N $ the normalization constant $ N=1-Exp(-w/k_B T)$.

The energy stored in this mode is $ Q(w,T) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty p(n) n w = w/(Exp(w/k_BT)-1) $

$ Q(0,T)=kT $ but $ Q(w,T) $ decreases almost exponentially and approaches zero for large $ w $.  There's no  transition , it's all smooth

If instead we vary T then as expected $Q(w,T)$ becomes almost linear as $T$ increases.

What is interesting is to look at $ Q(w,T)/k_B T $ which is a function of $ k_B T/w $ with a transition between $ k_B T=w/10 $ and $ k_B T \sim w 2 $ as seen on this image

[image: Q(w,T)/kT]